# Jquery Unable apply a tailwind class using addclass on list items also removeClass does not work

Tags: jquery, tailwind-css, codepen

```
Html Code:

<div class="container w-80 h-96 bg-gray-100 shadow-lg rounded-lg">
  <ul class="flex justify-center flex-col items-center cursor-pointer">
    <li class="option w-full flex justify-center items-center h-10 hover:bg-gray-200">Apples</li>
     <li class="option w-full flex justify-center items-center h-10 hover:bg-gray-200">Oranges</li>
    <li class="option w-full flex justify-center items-center h-10 hover:bg-gray-200">Mangoes</li>
    <li class="option flex justify-center items-center h-10 w-full hover:bg-gray-200">Banana</li>
  </ul>
</div>

JQuery Code:

$('li').click((e) => {
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.log("li clicked")
  $('li.bg-blue-300').removeClass("bg-blue-300")
  $(this).addClass("bg-blue-300")
})
```

Here is link to my code pen: 
https://codepen.io/shivakumarjakkani/pen/QWvjZdw 
I'm trying to add a specific class on a li element on the click event using jquery.
I can see that the click event is happening, but the class is not applied to the specified element.
Once the item is clicked it should turn to blue color indicating that the item is clicked and previously selected item should be de-highlighted, which is done by removeClass() method.
I see both addClass and removeClass are not working. 
Please help me what am I doing wrong here.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I logged `console.log($(this))`, it showed a window object.

So instead of:

```
$(this).addClass("bg-blue-300")
```

Use the event's target instead:

```
$(e.target).addClass("bg-blue-300")
```

Try a `console.log(e.target)` to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about jQuery or Tailwind - it's about arrow functions in Javascript and `this` context.

As it was pointed [here](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions#arrow-functions-have-no-this)

> ...arrow functions do not have this. If this is accessed, it is taken from the outside.

Because the arrow function doesn't have a `this`, it uses the parent's `this`. In your case it is window object as pointed by @PaulT and his solution will work.

Another way - not to use arrow function and replace it with

```
$('li').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.log("li clicked")
  $('li.bg-blue-300').removeClass("bg-blue-300")
  $(this).addClass("bg-blue-300")
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Iha Aliakseyenka for pointing out this in the arrow function. I was under impression that just by replacing the anonymous function with arrow function will have the same effect.